# How to delete a row of plist programmatically?

Tags: iphone

Can anyone help me to delete row of plist.

here `dictValue` is `NSNumber`, `dict` is `NSDictionary`, `keys` is `NSMutableArray` and `mutDict` is `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        dictValue = [dict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"Row Number - value %d", [dictValue intValue]);
        mutDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self doccuments_Path]];

        [mutDict removeObjectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        //[keys removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadData];
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `writeToFile: atomically:`method